# how to read S16LE file in python

Tags: python

I have a file which apparently is encoded with `S16LE` bit data?

How do i read it in python?
I see some reference here http://zulko.github.io/blog/2013/10/04/read-and-write-audio-files-in-python-using-ffmpeg/
but not able to translate it to my usecase?
Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness